# jQuery mobile enable button if checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I have this checkbox here and I'm trying to do is to enable the button if checkbox is checked but it is not working.

HTML:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" style="width:294px">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1" id="checkbox-1" class="chk"/>
            <label for="checkbox-1">I agree</label>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<input type="submit" id="submit" data-inline="true" data-theme="a" data-icon="check" value="&nbsp;Submit&nbsp;" disabled/>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
    $('.chk').change(function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked'))
            {
                $("#submit").removeAttr("disabled");
            }
        else
            {
                $("#submit").attr( "disabled", "disabled" );
            }               
    });
</script>
```

I can't see what's the problem. And I'm using JQM 1.3.2

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.chk').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#submit').button('enable');  
    }
    else {
        $('#submit').button('disable'); 
    }               
});
```

- http://jsfiddle.net/XAF3G/3/
- http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/buttons/buttons-methods.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`.button()`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/1.3/button/#method-enable) widget to *enable* or *disable* a button.

```
$(document).on("change", "#checkbox-1", function () {
  if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
    $("#submit").button("enable");
  } else {
    $("#submit").button("disable");
  }
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/tV3sD/)**

Answer (score 0):

use `button("enable")` and `button("disable")` you are using jquery mobile because

```
  $('.chk').change(function () {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

          $("#submit").button('enable');
      } else {
          $("#submit").button('disable');
      }
  });
```

here a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SAMgu/)

Comment: This is it, jQuery mobile replaces your ``<input type="submit" />`` with a custom button made of divs and spans, so it will look *nice* on a mobile phone. That's why the ``.prop('disabled')`` doesn't have any effect.

Comment: I think I'm getting close but I'm getting this error. **Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'button'**